# Python calculations not appearing, float numbers an issue?

Tags: python

1st time posting, trying to wrap my head around python, I'm solving a programming problem, asking for the commission of a sales woman. For some reason I cannot get the total commission to show, how does the float effect the final result? Thanks for the help. 
Here is my code thus far

```
#input for a sales womans sales per month in dollars, and her comission as a percent
#output comission for the month, need to convert percent to a decimal
#variables: Salesamount (float), comission rate(float) comssisoin earned (float)
#formula: comission earned = sales amount * (comissionrate/100)
print " This program will compute the comission earned for the month based on your sales for the month."
comission_rate = input("what is your comission rate percent? ") 
sales = raw_input("How many sales did you have this month? ")
total_com = sales * (comission_rate / 100)
print " your total comission for the month is "
print total_com
```

Comment: Why are you using `raw_input` for sales? That will get back a string.

Comment: `raw_input()` returns a `string`. You need to cast the input into `float` or `int` or any datatype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert all of your input values to floats:

```
print "This program will compute the comission earned for the month based on your sales for the month."
comission_rate = float(raw_input("what is your comission rate percent? "))
sales = float(raw_input("How many sales did you have this month? "))
total_com = sales * (comission_rate / 100)
print " your total comission for the month is "
print total_com
```

(exception handling for bad input left as an exercise for the reader)

Comment: For lazy typist like me: On Python 2.7 input is equivalent to eval(raw_input(prompt)) which works perfect for the task here.

Comment: @RobertCaspary you've just described why nobody should ever use `input` - do you know what happens if somebody enters `__import__("subprocess").call(['rm', '-rf', '/'])`?

Comment: actually using float for money is a bad idea, Decimal or integer number of pennies works better

Comment: @cmd: well, the specification is the specification. Usually homework problems don't let you redesign bad specs.

Comment: @Wooble and if the students don't bring it up how can you educate your teacher? ;-)

Comment: I had no idea that using float for money is a bad idea, I will keep that in mind.

Comment: @l4mpi May chroot be with you!  But for me..."WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified" So this won't cause any harm :-) But I know what you concerns are, which hopefully may be focused in the following homework ;-)